# How do I check if a variable has been initialized

Tags: java

First of all, I'm fairly new to Java, so sorry if this question is utterly simple.

The thing is: I have a `String[] s` made by splitting a String in which every item is a number. I want to cast the items of `s` into a `int[] n`.

`s[0]` contains the number of items that `n` will hold, effectively `s.length-1`. I'm trying to do this using a foreach loop:

```
int[] n;
for(String num: s){
    //if(n is not initialized){
        n = new int[(int) num];
        continue;
    }
    n[n.length] = (int) num;
}
```

Now, I realize that I could use something like this:

```
int[] n = new int[(int) s[0]];
for(int i=1; i < s.length; i++){
    n[i-1] = (int) s[i];
}
```

But I'm sure that I will be faced with that "if n is not initialized initialize it" problem in the future.

Comment: If s[0] is "effectively s.length-1", why include it at all?  Why not just let the length of s represent itself?

Comment: I agree, but have no control over that input. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't cast a `String` to an `int`. Java is strongly typed, and there is no implicit type conversion like you might find in a scripting language.

To convert a `String` to an `int`, use an explicit conversion, like `Integer.parseInt(String)`.

All member variables and elements of arrays are initialized with a default value. For `int` types, the value is 0. For reference types (any subtype of `Object`), the default value is `null`. Local variables don't get a default value, but the compiler analyzes the code to ensure that a value is assigned before the variable is read. If not, the code will not compile.

I think what you want is something like this:

```
int[] n = new int[Integer.parseInt(s[0]);
for (int idx = 0; idx < n; ++idx)
  n[idx] = Integer.parseInt(s[idx + 1]);
```

Comment: The part about reference types should be "reference types (any *subtype* of Object)", because `Object[]` is not a subclass of `Object`, but it is a subtype.

Comment: Thanks, after playing a bit with it I found that I had to do new Integer(s) to cast it.

Comment: @Javier: again: that's not "casting", that's "converting".

Comment: @Javier `new Integer(String)` is not a great API to use in most cases. If you want an `Integer` object, use `Integer.valueOf(String)` instead. This will minimize the number of distinct objects created. In this case, if you want a primitive `int`, use the `parseInt` method, which avoids creating the `Integer` object altogether.

Comment: @erickson Thanks a lot, that's great advise!
@Joachim thanks for the clarification, I come from a dynamic type background, so I don't fully understand the difference.

Comment: Note that `Integer.parseInt` throws the `NumberFormatException` unchecked exception if the String isn't an integer.

Answer (score 12):

You can't check if a variable is initialized in your code, because by definition reading from a variable that **might** not have been initialized leads to a compile-time error.

You can initialize the variable to `null` and check for that value **if** your variable is not a primitive type **and** `null` is not a valid value after the initialization.

In the specific example the second code you showed would definitely be cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

```
int[] n = null;
for(String num: s){
    if(n == null){
        n = new int[(int) num];
        continue;
    }
    n[n.length] = (int) num;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know I could assign null to any type of variable.

Comment: @Javier: only to variable/fields of reference types. So everything but `int`, `boolean`, `char`, `short`, `long`, `float`, `double`. Reference types include `Integer`, `int[]`, and an infinite number of other possibilities.

Comment: @polygenelubricants thanks for the clarification, so it's everything but the native types, right?

Comment: @Javier: Native has a different meaning in Java terminology. These 8 (I forgot to mention `byte` in above comment) types are called the "primitive" types. See JLS 4.2 http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.2 (and 4.3 for Reference types).

Answer (score 1):

If you initialize your variables or objects to `null` prior to using them,

```
String myVar1 = null;
Person bobby = null;
```

You could comparing the variable or object to not null,

```
if (myVar != null) {
  // myVar has a value.
}
```

Comment: only if it had initially and explicitly been initialized to null OR it is an object/class member

Comment: I had edited my answer, I should have been more clearer with my direction.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at the other datastructures in the collections framework.

-> http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/collections/Collection.html

ArrayList is a reasonable good alternative to arrays

Answer (score 1):

Only thing you can do is check against `null`. If your code is within a method, it will not compile if you don't initialize. So if it compiles and run you know it is initialized to at least `null` and then do the `null` checking.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, the closest thing to a "right way" to do this is to initialize the array to null.

On other points:

"n[n.length]" will throw an "index out of bounds" exception. Arrays have elements ranging from 0 to length-1. In any case, I think what you intended to say in the first case was "n[0]" and in the second was "n[i]".

Storing the size of an array in the first element is probably a bad idea. It can be done for an int array, but it would be messy in a String array and it wouldn't work at all for a boolean array. Even in the int case, you're now mixing two very different things in the same data structure, which is likely to be confusing. If the array size is fixed, "length" holds the size anyway. If the array size is variable and you're thinking that you're going to create an array big enough and then store the amount you actually use,  you are better off using ArrayList, which handles dynamic-size arrays cleanly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yeah, I got to the n.length always returning x, I didn't understand java's implementation of length, now that I see it, it makes a lot of sense, after all I initialized it with x elements, so n.length should always return x. And yeah I agree, storing the size in the first element is messy, but I have no control over that (I'm coding some exercises, and that's the expected input)

Comment: Ah, non-sensical requirements again lead to non-sensical design. Reminds me of an economics class I took in college. One chapter in the textbook talked about sunk costs and made the point that sunk costs are irrelevant to future plans. At the end of the chapter there was an exercise that said, "Suppose you get a job and your boss says, 'I don't care what they told you in economics class! I want you to factor in all our sunk costs or you're fired!' Are sunk costs now irrelevant to you?"

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue, checking if an `int` has been initialized. In my program, it was possible that it was initialized to `0`, so checking `if (int i = 0)` wouldn't do much good.

As a solution/work-around, I created a `boolean` variable that is set when the `int` is initialized. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You can check for `null`:

```
int[] n;
for(String num: s){
    if(n == null) {
        n = new int[(int) num];
    }
    n[n.length] = (int) num;
}
```

Note that this can only happen if n is a class member. If it is a local variable, the compiler will not let you do anything with it without it being initialized.

Comment: This won't compile: local variables are *not* set to `null` by default. (additionally there's the problem with the int-casting that won't work as @erickson noted).